# How to center the content of a page

Tags: html, css

Below are the code for my asp.net form,i want to display the form content in center.The style for the first div is working it is making the form center but for the second div the contents are not centered...

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  #frm { position: fixed;
         top: 50%;
         left: 50%;
         width: 50%;
         height: 200px;
         margin: -100px 0 0 -25%;}
  </style>
<body>
<div id="frm">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="margin-left:auto;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtbx" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_click" />
    <asp:Button ID="button2" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="btn_clicked" />
    <hr />
    <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your style with the below one.

```
#frm { position: fixed;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     width: 50%;
     height: 200px;
     margin: -100px 0 0 -25%;
     text-align: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `margin: auto;` to center any div in his parent. If you want to use this, you will have to set the width of the div though.

```
#frm {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#form1 {
    width: 100%;
}

#form1 > div {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```